# WooCommerce deleted all my menus, categories, theme, pages

Tags: plugins

i have installed
WooCommerce plugin and i have supersized that all my menus, categories, theme, pages ....etc have deleted
the only good news is my products didn't delete

i have tried to deactivate it but nothing goes back

how could i undo these changes 
please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce gives the option to use their own theme so perhaps this is your issue. 
If that’s the case, goto Themes and activate your old theme and everything should go back to normal.